# How to disable or uninstall google play newsstand in android programmatically

Tags: performance

I want to disable or uninstall google play newsstand in android programmatically, because in my phone when i swipe wallpaper in that google play newsstand running always, so that my internet getting slow. Advice me any solution for this.

Comment: why would you want to do that **"programatically"**?

Comment: Because in Apps Manager i had to disable that application, after that it working as usual. so that i am asking. How can i able to do that?